# Facebook FQL Bug -FQL query on "stream" table using "updated_time" column does no longer returns correct results

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

i have encounter same bug as show on below bug page.

FQL query on "stream" table using "updated_time" column does no longer returns correct results

```
SELECT post_id,updated_time, actor_id, target_id, message,comments FROM stream WHERE source_id  = " + PageID + " AND updated_time >" + unixfromdate
```

see below bug URL.

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/316607451683448?browse=search_4eed342fe60cc52875050191

is there any work around?

Brijesh

Answer (score 0):

This is FB bug. There are at least two bugs opened in FB on this matter:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/322648647820172/
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/436202526413815/

I have found another one: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/105849459574668
and it was closed with comment like - "this bug didn't have much impact on developers community, so we closed it"!

Please, report about your problems - otherwise FB will never fix it!